# Blackberry Webworks: Is the payment service(blackberry.payment.developmentMode) supported on OS 7 and earlier devices

Tags: blackberry, in-app-purchase, payment, blackberry-webworks

I am creating an app using HTML5 webworks on Blackberry 10, However I want to use webworks on OS7 and earlier devices as well.I also want to support payment service for In-App purchases on my app. Does the payment service API of webworks work on OS7 and earlier devices too?

When I use

```
blackberry.payment.developmentMode =  true;
```

It is found to be undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the [Payment API](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.payment.html) is supported on BlackBerry 7.

Make sure to define this feature in your config.xml file:

```
<feature id="blackberry.payment" />
```